# Force opportunity status update when product is added

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have the following code:

```
AND(Product_Count__c<>0,IF(OR(ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Scheduled')),true,false))
```

This works but the problem is you can't add the product without changing the status first, we have an additional validation that I can't change where a product has to be added before the StageName can be changed from "Scheduled"

I wanted to have the user add a product then force them to change the status. Can this be done with a validation rule or do I need a flow?

Comment: May I know, Is the field `Product_Count__c` is a Rollup summary type field or any custom field with Number type?

Comment: @MohanRaj yes, it's a roll up summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SFDC, `Validation Rule` only works when the record is created/updated action only. So you can't use the `Validation Rule` to force the user to update the `Status` after the product added.

So yes. As you mentioned, Please use **flow** or any other process (like process builder, Workflow) to `create the task`/`send an email` action to inform the user to update the `Status` once after the user added the product.

Thanks.